# Publish fanout array with RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq

How can I send an array via fanout with `basic_publish`?

I'm doing this:

```
// $this->message is the array to send
$props = array('content_type' => 'application/json');
$msg = new AMQPMessage($this->message, $props);

$channel->basic_publish($msg, $this->fanoutName);
```

And I get this error:

> ErrorException in AMQPChannel.php line 1098:
>   mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I search a lot and I can't find a way to send an array instead of a string.

Comment: What would be an example for `$this->message`? How is it supposed to formulate a message for the given array?

Comment: @FirstOne the array is receive from another function, the array content is for example: `$this->message = array('a' => 'b');`

Comment: Alright. And how should the message be formulated based on the array? I mean, what's the expected message given that array? **Edit:** put those informations in the question, please (it might increase your odds on getting an answer)

Comment: Since the parameter kinda expects a string, you could use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or loop the given array to generate the expected message.

Comment: @FirstOne Will be something like this: `$this->message = array('id' => 12345, 'status' => 'available', 'content' => 'the content...');`

Comment: It seems like I couldn't make myself understood. Say we have that array `'id' => 12345, etc..`. How should the message be? Should it be something like: `The ID is 12345 with status available and text: the content...`?

Comment: Here is an example of what I meant: [https://eval.in/612447](https://eval.in/612447). If the script expects a string, you'll have to -somehow- make the given array become a string.

Comment: @FirstOne The problem is not the message array. I want to send an array via RabbitMQ using a fanout exchange and I can't find the way to do that with the RabbitMQ PHP Library because in another languages like Java or Objective-C there is a way to do that with their respective libraries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

convert the array to JSON using `json_encode`

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php

```
// $this->message is the array to send
$props = array('content_type' => 'application/json');

// convert the array to json
$data = json_encode($this->message);

// send the resulting json data
$msg = new AMQPMessage($data, $props);

$channel->basic_publish($msg, $this->fanoutName);
```

Comment: This is not a solution.